# Configurate MSSQL Server with Django

Tags: sql-server, django

I have installed

```
**appdirs==1.4.3
asgiref==3.2.7
distlib==0.3.0
Django==2.1.15
django-mssql==1.8
django-mssql-backend==2.8.1
django-pyodbc-azure==2.1.0.0
filelock==3.0.12
pyodbc==4.0.30
pytz==2019.3
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
virtualenv==20.0.18
virtualenvwrapper-win==1.2.6**
```

My settings.py file in the database section looks like this

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'localhost',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'root*+123456*+789',
        'PORT': '1433',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following error after run `py manage.py migrate`

File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 167, in ensure_defaults
        conn = self.databases[alias]
      File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in **get**
        res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 154, in databases
        if self._databases[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS] == {}:
    KeyError: 'default'

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 305, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 199, in __getitem__
    self.ensure_defaults(alias)
  File "C:\Users\z003vuxz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 169, in ensure_defaults
    raise ConnectionDoesNotExist("The connection %s doesn't exist" % alias)
django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection default doesn't exist
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your `DATABASES`-setting is incorrect, see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases) for details.

What you need is:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

The configuration for the connection needs to be inside of `'default': {...}`, you placed it directly inside of `DATABASES`.

Comment: yes you are right! I forgot to added to the question. Originaly I have it with the default tag